# Static members inheritance and protection

Tags: c++

i do have a question about static members inheritance and them protection in C++. I hope i will be clear enough since is not always easy to write the mind states :) I'm writing an simple (textual parser) for an graphical program that is loading textual file with custom formatting, now the text part is almost done and now i need to produce some objects to feed them with data i loaded from the file.

This question i believe belong to hour 1. of C++ but im stuck. For example i loaded from the text file just 2 types of logical "nodes", LAYER and PLINE, they also have they attributes which can or cannot be common to both. The relation of LAYER to PLINE and back is totally irrelevant now, the thing that is bugging me is how to connect and handle attributes of both:

Suppose i chose **DataObj** as the base class for both. DataObj has an member called "name" because both LAYER and PLINE can have a name. LAYER has an attribute that is common only to layer for eg. "locked", and PLINE has an attribute that is common only to pline eg. "color". In the "school way" of doing things it would look like:

```
/// i use const char* for everything to not complicate things ... 
...
class DataObj {
  ...
  const char* name;
  ...
}
...
class Layer : public DataObj {
 ...
 const char* locked;
 ...
}
...
class Pline : public DataObj {
 ...
 const char* color;
 ... 
}
...
int main(){
   Layer* l = new Layer();
   l.name = "first layer";
   l.locked = "false";

   Pline* p = new Pline();
   p.name = "wonderful line";
   p.color = "0xFF3300";
}
...
```

Now i want to do it more "dynamically" in the way i really don't bother with static typed member names (and possibly them accessors in the future), especially when feeding objects with data coming from the parser. I mean is easy to do it with 2 only node types but i will have more than dozens of them.

So the concept i want to do is to "statically" push vector of allowed attributes for each node type (class) and then only to do checks if this attribute is allowed in the object and set it during parsing. I possibly want to have 2 important members 1. is std::map of kv pairs, the second is the static vector of allowed attributes for certain node. Following the code typed before:

```
...
class DataObj {
  ...
  static std::vector<const char*> allowedAttrs;
  std::map <const char*, const char*> attrs;

  private: 
     static bool isInit;
  ...
}
...
DataObj::DataObj(){
  if(!isInit)
    allowedAttrs.push_back("name");
  isInit = true;
}
...
Layer::Layer(){
  if(!isInit) // private static for Layer
     allowedAttrs.push_back("locked");
}
...
Pline::Pline(){
  if(!isInit) // private static for Pline
     allowedAttrs.push_back("color");
}
...
```

The problem i'm getting here is probably visible from the moon. If we init frst a new Layer then a new Pline, Pline will have name, locked and color in the allowedAttrs vector and that's not correct, becaue "locked" should be only valid for layer node.

So i need some way to solve this problem in the way the member "allowedAttrs" become "private" for the un-common attributes like "locked" in Layer object but also retain its "public" nature from the super class "DataObj" - so it can catch the shared attributes like "name". In other words i don't want to "break" the "inheritance flow" going up to the base class, and define new variable for each node class (object) repeating the same code over and over again. (something like an virtual variable).

I hope this question is not (so) dumb, and really will appreciate your answers.

Comment: Please make your question concise and to the point. It'll help you get you answers quickly.

Comment: as the base class constructor is called first, will the other push_backs ever happen?

Comment: I think you have completely misunderstood how `static` works

Comment: `i use const char* for everything to not complicate things` Not correct IMO. You should have used `std::string` instead.

Comment: what is wrong with const char* ?

Comment: nothing is wrong with it, it just complicates things. string object is way simpler to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) I would use seperate static members for each type to hold the allowed attributes for each type.
2) Move the static members into functions, which is safer, and possibly avoids checking to see if it's initialized all the time (depending on how good your compiler is and other details)
3) Don't use `const char*` except for very specific things.  If you don't know what those things are, always use `std::string`.  In this case, we *have* to use `std::string`.
4) I changed `allowedAttrs` from a vector to a `set`, which might be faster for large numbers of attributes, and slower for smaller numbers, maybe.

Here's the base:

```
class DataObj {
  const std::set<std::string>& get_allowed_data_attributes() static {    
    static std::set<std::string> allowedAttrs = {"name"};
    return allowedAttrs;
  }
  std::map <std::string, std::string> attrs;
  public:
     DataObj(){ }
     void set_attribute(std::string key, std::string value) {
         auto it = get_allowed_data_attributes().find(key);
         if (it  == get_allowed_data_attributes().end())
            throw bad_key_exception(key);
         attrs.insert(std::make_pair(std::move(key), std::move(value)));
     }
     const std::string& get_attribute(const std::string& key) const {
         auto it = attrs().find(key);
         if (it  == attrs().end())
            throw bad_key_exception(key);
         return it->second;
     }
};
```

Here's the derived:

```
class Layer : public DataObj {
  const std::set<std::string>& get_allowed_data_attributes() static {    
    static std::set<std::string> allowedAttrs = {"locked"};
    return allowedAttrs;
  }
  public:
     DataObj(){ }
     void set_attribute(std::string key, std::string value) {
         auto it = get_allowed_data_attributes().find(key);
         if (it  == get_allowed_data_attributes().end())
            DataObj::set_attribute(std::move(key), std::move(value));
         else
            attrs.insert(std::make_pair(std::move(key), std::move(value)));
     }
     const std::string& get_attribute(const std::string& key) const {
         auto it = attrs().find(key);
         if (it  == attrs().end())
            return DataObj::get_attribute(key);
         else
            return it->second;
     }
};
```

Note that if you give it an invalid key, it throws a `bad_key_exception`, which you will have to add.  Be sure it inherits from `std::runtime_error`.

Comment: Thank you also for yor powerful solution and tips. I have one question, can set_attribute and get_attribute methods be defined only once in the base class as protected?

Comment: @cybercow: sure, that works fine.  (Also, I fixed a bug in the code)

Comment: Thank you again, really will give a boost to my project! Really didn't had chance to use std::string(s), and possibly my first assumption was that using c-strings will produce a faster code? The parser that i'm writing will parse ~half-million lines of raw textual data (mainly spatial coordinates) and feed the stack of objects just like the example you coded. So for example you can have 100 Layers and 100000 Plines. Presumably was stupid from me to assume that c-strings are faster, but i started with c-strings and didn't wanted to mix them together

Comment: @cybercow: cstrings _are_ faster, but only if you get them right, and the speed increase is like losing 20 pounds before driving a car.  And if you make a mistake, the car explodes.  Use `std::string`.  Always get it right, and worry about speed later.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would implement your vector of allowed attributes. I would have each type contain a list of allowed attributes, copying their base class's list during initialization.

```
class DataObj {
  ...
  static std::vector<std::string> allowedAttrs;
  std::map <std::string, std::string> attrs;

  private: 
     static bool isInit;
  ...
}
class Layer {
  static std::vector<std::string> allowedAttrs;
  ...
};
class PLine {
  static std::vector<std::string> allowedAttrs;
}
...
DataObj::DataObj(){
  if(!isInit)
    allowedAttrs.push_back("name");
  isInit = true;
}
...
Layer::Layer(){
  if(!isInit) { // private static for Layer
     allowedAttrs = DataObj::allowedAttrs;
     allowedAttrs.push_back("locked");
  }
}
...
Pline::Pline(){
  if(!isInit) { // private static for Pline
     allowedAttrs = DataObj::allowedAttrs;
     allowedAttrs.push_back("color");
  }

}
```

Notes:

- Use `std::string`, not `char*` for both the vector and the map. While the `vector<char*>` could potentially be useful,  `map<char*,char*>` is just a bug.
- You could avoid duplicating the base class's list by having the lookup function be a little smarter.

Comment: Thank you for your response i really appreciate it,  well im just finally digging into C++ and mostly older docs always somehow use char in some of its variations so my thoughs were is correct to use it.

Comment: Not every use of `char*` or `const char*` is incorrect, but enough of them are. I **never** recommend `char*` to a new C++ programmer.